# Shell script to archive & delete files older than 5 days based on created date of the files

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to compress 5 days' worth log at a time and moving the compressed files to another location and deleting the logs files from original location. I need bash script to accomplish this. I got the files compressed using the below command, but not able to move them to the archive folder. I also need to compress based on date created. Now it's compressing all the files starting with a specific name.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd "C:\Users\ann\logs"
for filename in acap*.log*; do
# this syntax emits the value in lowercase: ${var,,*}  (bash version 4)
mkdir -p archive
 gzip  "$filename_.zip" "$filename"
mv "$filename" archive

done
```

Comment: Looks like it's time to hire a developer.

Comment: i did the following, but it just moves teh file from one location to another.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
cd "C:\Users\ann\logs"
for filename in acap*.log*; do
  # this syntax emits the value in lowercase: ${var,,*}  (bash version 4)
    mkdir -p archive
  mv "$filename" archive
  
done

Comment: You can click on [edit] to add the code to the question itself, it's easier to read with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p archive
for file in $(find . -mtime +3 -type f -printf "%f ")
do
    if [[ "$file" =~ ^acap.*\.log$ ]]
    then
        tar -czf archive/${file}.tar.gz $file
        rm $file
    fi
done
```

This finds all files in the current directory that match the regex and compresses them in an tar for every file. Then it deletes all the files.

Comment: I want to zip individual files matching the criteria and move them to another folder namely /archive or so. This creates a single tar with all those files.

Comment: @Ann You want one zip per file?

Comment: yes..and all these individual archive files should be moved to an archive folder from the original folder

Comment: @Ann Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked.. Can i enhance this to logic to just zip and remove files older than 3 days

Comment: replace ``ls`` by ``find . -mtime +3 -type f -printf "%f "``

Comment: It worked in windows but the same not working in linux.

Comment: lot of errors like : command not found
: command not found
'rc.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `do . The archive file gets created multiple times too. i just need it to be created once..if already exist dont craete again.

Comment: @Ann What linux are you using? It should totally work.

Comment: 3.0.101-0.47.106

Comment: @Ann I mean what linux distribution? (Ubuntu, Debian, Red Hat, ...)

Comment: SUSE Linux enterprise server 11

Comment: @Ann Try changing the first line to ``#!/bin/sh``. That's the last thing I can think of.

Comment: No luck. The condition if [[ "$file" =~ ^acap.*\.log$ ]] doesnt wrk

Comment: Maybe your bash version is too old. What version do you have? ``bash --version``. Try to update it.